# Is it a standard to have an empty `index.php` in root of Plugin?

Tags: plugins

Can anyone tell why in all plugins, the `index.php` is empty? What's the point of it, i can't understand, as it doesn't add any security at all to website, and makes the plugin structure "1-file" more.

p.s. Themes do have `index.php`,

Answer (score 1):

It helps to prevent the contents of the plugins folder from being listed if someone was to browse to it. So, yes, it does provide a form of security.

If someone browses to the plugin folder with their web browser, it will just display a blank page instead of a directory listing.

Comment: no, i mean, why the plugin main file is  not written in index.php

Comment: Because that's not how the WordPress plugin API works

Comment: can you mention two words about "that's not how the WordPress plugin API works", how writing plugin in `index.php` conflicts with API? thanks